# Why does the Laplace Transform fail to solve algebraic equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Given the idea behind the Laplace Transform solving ODEs, I would expect it to be possible to solve algebraic equations via a similar technique.  For example, $\sin t = \cos t$ would transform to $\frac{1}{s^2 + 1} = \frac{s}{s^2 + 1}$, which can be manipulated to $1 = \frac{1}{s^2}$.  However, the inverse transform of this would be $\delta = t$, which is not a valid answer.  What is the reason that this technique fails to solve algebraic equations?

Comment: So the laplace transform doesn't solve (linear, with constant coefficients) ODEs so much as transform them into algebraic equations which you then solve *via* the normal methods. You can think of regular algebric tricks and substitutions as transformations, although they won't be integral transforms. With the use of any such trick, you are figuratively kicking the can down the road, hoping that the trick may be useful. Sometimes things cancel out nicely, other times it gives you an even bigger mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving ODEs by Laplace transform solves only **linear** ODEs.  I think you would agree that for algebraic equations, we do not need such technique to solve **linear** equations.

**Your example:**  What it tells us is: if we have $\sin t = \cos t$ for all $t$, then we get some conclusion.  Of course any conclusion we draw from a false hypothesis like that is worthless.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin t =\cos t$ doesn't make any sense, you mean $$\sin t = h\ast \cos( t)$$ 
Taking the Laplace transform $$\frac{1}{s^2 + 1} = H(s)\frac{s}{s^2 + 1}$$
$$H(s) = \frac1s, \qquad h(t) = 1$$ which is the correct solution $$h\ast \cos(t)=\int_0^t \cos(u)du = \sin t$$
(there are several traps about the support, the convolution and the domain of convergence we are using, replace $h(t)=1$ and $\sin t $ by $h(t)=1_{t >0}$ and $1_{t > 0}\sin t$  to make it clear)